# Pure CSS Context Highlighting

Tags: html, css

Having a few issues here - I am sort of almost there, but now completely stuck and hoping that some of you CSS/HTML Gurus can offer some assistance.

I am trying to do a "pure CSS based context highlight with tooltip" - I've pretty much got most of it together apart from the tooltip (lol!). I also wanted the tooltip to "hover" when the mouse moves over a field.

Currently, in Safari as well it seems that the "select" (yellow border) from the browser appears around the entire highlight ...

If someone can assist with these issues - love you long time!

```css
#fields {
  padding-left:50px;
}

#example {
  float: left;
  width:500px;
  padding-right:40px;
}
#example label {
  display: block;
  float:left;
}
#example dt {
  float: left; 
  width: 50px; 
  clear: both; 
  padding-left: 5px; 
  z-index: 1; 
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#example .tooltip {
  float:right;
  width:200px;
  margin-top:5px;
  visibility:hidden;
}
#example dd {
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
}
#example input[type=text], #example textarea {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  width: 196px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}
#example input[type=text]:focus, #example textarea:focus, #example .tooltip:focus {
  border: #E9E9E9 solid ; 
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 5px 200px 5px 100px; 
  left: -100px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 0;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="fields">
  <form id="example" action="" method=""> 
    <dt><label for="name">Name</label></dt> 
    <dd><input id="name" name="name" type="text" /></dd> 
    <div class="tooltip">some special tooltip</div>
    <dt><label for="email">Email</label></dt> 
    <dd><input id="email" name="email" type="text" /></dd>
    <div class="tooltip">some special tooltip</div>
    <dt><label for="message">Message</label></dt> 
    <dd><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols=""></textarea></dd>
  </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Re the tooltip part of your q:

For cross-browser tooltips with all the extras, I suggest http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/

Larry

ps. Are you sure that you want the meta tag to select 8859-1 character set? (Rather than UTF-8.)

Comment: Hey Larry K - thanks for the response :) Yeah re-UTF - just a test page. I am trying for CSS/HTML based highlighting only - no JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Might help with the border:

```
.noselect {
-moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla */
-khtml-user-select: none; /* safari */
-o-user-select: none; /* opera */
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Removes the visual indications of highlighting text (in supported browsers).